# Spring Boot & Thymeleaf - Best Way to Save a Search Form for subsequent calls

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am working on a Spring Boot app that implements a search form page so that the user is able to narrow search results, this works with Pageable and QueryDSL to fullfill all the needs, and I am temporaryly saving the search form on a bean to pass it to Spring Data and return the search results.

The thing is, the results page implements links for the other pages of the search query like this

First Page | 1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 | …10 |  Next

This links are like this: "/contract/nextPage?page=1&size=20”

But when the user, for example clicks on any of this links, obviously, I do not have anymore the "search parameters" that where on the first request to the controller.

So what's the best way to "store" this information so I can reuse it to get the next pages and how can I do it?

Many thanks to you all and sorry if this is too newbie question.

Comment: Any Suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `model.addAttribute` within controller to add `Page` or `Size`.

You can send them there by `JavaScript` or Form in `Thymeleaf` when needed.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't think you understand exactly what I asked. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You did not specify e.g `But when the user, for example clicks on any of this links, `
what links? Are they from your server ? if so you can use my answer.

If i did not understood corectly then try describing your problem better.